# Prevent blocking of appengine tests with Windows firewall

Tags: windows, google-app-engine

When running appengine tests with windows10 I continually get firewall popups. Since the origin path of the file making the call changes on every test I get popups everytime.

Is there a way to eliminate the firewall popups without fully disabling the firewall.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can disable the popups.  In the Windows Firewall control panel, go to Advanced Settings, then select Windows Firewall Properties.

For each relevant firewall profile, select Customize from the Settings box.  Change the "Display a notification" option to "No".

(In a domain environment, you can also do this via group policy if you need to reconfigure many machines at once.)